# Accessing indices in dynamic List in Python does not work

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm programming a simple Weighted sum model in Python and i want to save the winner of each vector. Therefor, i create a counter list in which i save the amount of wins i got for 2 winner *(Counter List has 2 Objects ( 2 possible winner) with 3 items (Decision problems) with 2 items (each decision)))*

I'm declaring counter as:

```
counter = [[[0,0]]*len(maniArrays)]*len(maniArrays[0])
```

And have a simple loop that looks for the numbers that won and add it to that counter

```
# For each Element in [[1, 9], [2, 9], [2, 6]]
    for paar_idx, paar in enumerate(maniArrays):

        # For each in [1, 9]
        for einzel_idx, einzel in enumerate(paar):

            # komb[paar_idx] = [1, 2, 2]
            if einzel == komb[paar_idx]:

                counter[max_idx][paar_idx][einzel_idx] += 1;
```

My problem now is that it results in adding +1 to just one index at each pair when it shoulve add at [max_idx][paar_idx][einzel_idx] (max_idx is the winner and should point to the vector), resulting in, for example:

```
Combination  [1, 2, 2]  ->  [[1, 2, 4], [5, 2, 2]]  ->  Winner: A 2
Counter (before) [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
Counter (after) [[[3, 0], [3, 0], [3, 0]], [[3, 0], [3, 0], [3, 0]]]
```

I thought it's an error in my code, but when i declare the array as

```
counter = [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

it works, so the problem must be in declaring the list. But i want to declare this list dynamically, so what can i do?

Extra: Declaring the counter like that results in:

```
Combination  [1, 2, 2]  ->  [[1, 2, 4], [5, 2, 2]]  ->  Winner: A 2
Counter(after): [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]]]
```

Comment: This is because all the inside lists are the same list; you can check with `id()` which lists sre the same and which are separate ones

Comment: OK, but how can i generate those lists without them being the same inside of it?

Comment: Let me write up a proper answer now that it's not the middle of the night :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that all the inside `[0, 0]` are the same list; you can check with `id()` which lists are the same and which are the separate ones.

This is actually a wider pitfall in Python — in several circumstances, `[...]` makes a list, which is then reused even though you might want a new one. The same applies to dictionaries, sets, objects — anything you can modify in place (the keyword to search for is "mutable"). Another place where this is a problem is in function parameter defaults, which is why you often see the default for a parameter being `None` rather than `[]`, with the first lines of the function checking for `None` and setting the parameter to `[]`

In this case, you have:

```
>>> counter = [[[0,0]] * 2] * 3
>>> counter
[[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]
>>> counter[0][0][0] += 1
>>> counter
[[[1, 0], [1, 0]], [[1, 0], [1, 0]], [[1, 0], [1, 0]]]
>>>
```

which is because the inner-most `[0, 0]` only gets created once and then put into the list multiple times; you can check that they are all the same:

```
>>> id(counter[0][0])
139767674616832
>>> id(counter[0][1])
139767674616832
>>>
```

One way to work around this is to use a list comprehension instead, like this:

```
>>> counter = [[[0, 0] for _i in range(2)] for _j in range(3)]
>>> counter
[[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]
>>> counter[0][0][0] += 1
>>> counter
[[[1, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

you can check that the inner lists are separate objects:

```
>>> id(counter[0][0])
139767674616896
>>> id(counter[0][1])
139767674617280
>>>
```

A couple of alternatives:

- If you find the list comprehension notation too dense, you can instead write out the code using ordinary `for` loops. This can be clearer:

  ```
  >>> counter = []
  >>> for j in range(3):
  ...   counter.append([])
  ...   for _i in range(2):
  ...     counter[j].append([0, 0])
  ... 
  >>> counter
  [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]
  >>> counter[0][0][0] += 1
  >>> counter
  [[[1, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]
  ```
- Depending on the rest of the code, you could instead use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter); in both cases, you start with an empty data structure and only add elements that are needed. They're both quite a different data structure from a list of lists of lists, though; depending on the rest of the code, they may work better or worse. In particular, (a) they won't keep the order, and (b) they'll omit the unused entries. On the other hand, (c) if you weren't going to do anything with the unused/zero entries anyway, no need to store or process them...

  ```
  >>> import collections
  >>> counter = collections.Counter()
  >>> counter[(0, 0, 0)] += 1
  >>> counter
  Counter({(0, 0, 0): 1})
  ```

  you can then iterate through it using something like:

  ```
  for (max_idx, paar_idx, einzel_idx), count in counter.items():
    ...
  ```